# Why do we set classpath in ant

Tags: java, ant, classpath

Below is the code for setting class path in `ant`.

```
<path id="build.classpath">
   <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
     <include name="**/*.jar" />
   </fileset>
</path>
<target name="compile" depends="clean">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="build.classpath" />
</target>
```

Why do we need to set `classpath` in `ant` ?

Answer (score 1):

Think of ant as a framework to run your build tasks - compiling the code, running the (unit) tests, etc. In order to properly compile and execute your  (test) code, java will need access to the third party libraries you may be using (e.g., JUnit for running unit tests). The classpath tells java where these JARs are located, so it can use them.

Comment: Can we see how java use those JARs in our pgm??